# php code for save and update using same button

Tags: php

table name -  user_table

i try to save and update value from single Save button.

but I can not understand how to merge save and update code in 'if else' using certain condition.

Below is my **save** code :

```
<?php
        require_once('includes/config.php');        
        $errors = array();
        $Admin = new admins;                
        if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {
             $errors = $Admin->validate_cms_user_table();       
             if(!count($errors))
             {  
                    $table = $Admin->user_table;    
                    $fields_func = array ('password' =>"md5('{$_POST['password']}')");
                    unset ($_POST['password']);
                    if($Admin->save_advance($table,$_POST,$fields_func))            
                    {
                        $_SESSION['message'] = "User Created Successfully";                 
                        header("Location:user_master.php");
                        exit;           
                    }
             }    
        }
?>
```

**Update code**

```
if($Admin->save($Admin->user_table,$_POST,"id=".$_GET['id']))
            {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Updated Successfully";
                header("Location: user_master.php");
                exit;

            }
```

**Update Condition**

```
if(!isset($_GET['catid']))
    {
//Then Save Code
}
Else
{
//Update Code
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you try to achive.

Comment: You need to pass through the user ID in your post array. If the ID is present and the row exists in your database run an UPDATE query if not you need to run an INSERT query.

Comment: I only need to merge update code on above save code using below update condition.plz suggest me i tried many times but it only add new record each time..